# Smooth ProgressBar in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, progress-bar

I'm using the ProgressBar control in a WPF application and I'm getting this old, Windows 3.1 Progress*Blocks* thing. In VB6, there was a property to show a *smooth* ProgressBar. Is there such a thing for WPF?

Comment: Not an answer, but on the topic of progress bars and smooth operation, here is a good paper on different functions: http://www.chrisharrison.net/projects/progressbars/ProgBarHarrison.pdf

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[This](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/323116) KB article seems to explain what you are looking for... there is a link to a VB version of the article too.

Comment: Oh. Well at least is says: "You can't do that anymore!". Sadly, the solution itself is a bit to minimalistic - I seriously doubt it will work with animations. Thank you, though.

Comment: That is a WinForms solution.  In WPF, you should just create a new ControlTemplate for the ProgressBar.

Answer (score 2):

I was not able to find a direct solution for this. But I found something even better. In WPF, you can use Windows Themes. I am using Windows XP, and having Vista-Aero Theme on my WPF Application, making all controls look like Vista-Aero.

Here's the code...

Go to Application.xaml.vb and write...

```
  Enum appThemes
        Aero
        Luna
        LunaMettalic
        LunaHomestead
        Royale
    End Enum

Private Sub Application_Startup(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.StartupEventArgs) Handles Me.Startup

        setTheme(appThemes.Aero)

    End Sub

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Function to set the default theme of this application
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="Theme">
    ''' Theme of type appThemes
    ''' </param>
    ''' <remarks></remarks>
    Public Sub setTheme(ByVal Theme As appThemes)

        Dim uri As Uri

        Select Case Theme
            Case appThemes.Aero
                ' Vista Aero Theme
                uri = New Uri("PresentationFramework.Aero;V3.0.0.0;31bf3856ad364e35;component\\themes/Aero.NormalColor.xaml", UriKind.Relative)

            Case appThemes.Luna
                ' Luna Theme
                uri = New Uri("PresentationFramework.Luna;V3.0.0.0;31bf3856ad364e35;component\\themes/Luna.NormalColor.xaml", UriKind.Relative)

            Case appThemes.LunaHomestead
                ' Luna Mettalic
                uri = New Uri("PresentationFramework.Luna;V3.0.0.0;31bf3856ad364e35;component\\themes/Luna.Metallic.xaml", UriKind.Relative)

            Case appThemes.LunaMettalic
                ' Luna Homestead
                uri = New Uri("PresentationFramework.Luna;V3.0.0.0;31bf3856ad364e35;component\\themes/Luna.Homestead.xaml", UriKind.Relative)

            Case appThemes.Royale
                ' Royale Theme
                uri = New Uri("PresentationFramework.Royale;V3.0.0.0;31bf3856ad364e35;component\\themes/Royale.NormalColor.xaml", UriKind.Relative)

        End Select

        ' Set the Theme
        Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(Application.LoadComponent(uri))

    End Sub
```

(I hope you can convert it to C#)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you want to do.
If you simply want a progress bar that "sweeps" from side to side like on starting Vista you could use: IsIndetermined = true.

If you actually want to go from 0% to 100% you have to either animate over the value as shown in this example on msdn: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.progressbar.aspx 
or set the value explicitly either in code-behind (most likely from a background worker) or through a binding to a changing value.

Nevertheless the WPF ProgressBar should always be "smooth", there is the possibility that the UI will default to a more simpler version through a RemoteDesktop connection.

Answer (score 0):

I recently was annoyed by the appearance of my progress bars on XP after developing on Vista.  I didn't want to try suggestions I'd seen for loading the Vista styles out of dll's, but [this article](http://www.theamoebaproject.com/blog/aquaseal/look-and-feel-progressbar) gave me just what I was looking for.  vista appearance - no new classes.  Plus it has the glassy highlight on a timer.  No pictures on the article, but it looks just like Vista's ProgressBar.

Comment: http://mattserbinski.com/blog/look-and-feel-progressbar

get ProgressBarExamples.zip, in Window1.xaml there is a styleProgressBarVista which you can extract into your xaml, or a ResourceDictionary